# Download Apps for Android 3

Tags: 3.2-honeycomb

I have an Android 3 device but the play store doesn't work.  I have tried updating it.

Is there a way to force the download of apps?

Comment: Google Play services and the Market (ie Play Store) should update themselves as long as you have a valid Google account on your device and there is sufficient space on the device. Try going here first: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms and click Install/Installed button and select your device press Install. After it is successfully installed, reboot and open the Market app, it should open but don't do anything but close it, wait about 15 minutes and it should auto update to the Play Store and you are good to update/install apps.

Comment: @acejavelin your answer worked thank you!  You may post it as answer if you would like or I can self answer.

Comment: Glad it worked... posted as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play services and the Market (ie Play Store) should update themselves as long as you have a valid Google account on your device and there is sufficient space on the device. Try going [here](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) first to update Google Play Services manually and click Install/Installed button and select your device press Install. After it is successfully installed, reboot and open the Market app, it should open but don't do anything but close it, wait about 15 minutes and it should auto update to the Play Store and you are good to update/install apps.